# How to disable cache for specific test class laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I was writing Integration test for a service class. I want to disable caching while running a laravel test class.

We can set cache driver to disable caching for whole laravel project but
Is there any way to disable caching for specific test class ?

Comment: You can try `Config::set('cache.default', 'array')` in the setup of the test class, i'm not sure if it actually works, worth a try

Comment: @Lk77 Thank you for the response, I will try this & let you know !

Comment: @Lk77, It's working ! Can you make sure it doesn't affect other tests ?

Comment: Each test method should be isolated by default, so i think so, try do put a `dd(config('cache.default'))` on another unrelated test